# How to remove edit and delete button from minicart?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, mini-cart, magento2.2

I tried,

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\minicart\item\default.html
```

I removed below lines

```
       <div class="product actions">
            <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
            <div class="primary">
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div class="secondary">
                <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                   class="action delete">
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But still there is no effect. Can anyone tell me the correct way to do?

Comment: You also have to change in pub/static or do setup:upgrade and deploy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not change directly core files, you should **override default.html in custom theme**

**Copy**
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

**to**`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

And now remove `product actions` div(Edit And Delete div) from `default.html`

**There are two way to see changes of static files**

1. By removing the same file from **pub/static** **OR**
2. Do **static-content:deploy**

For example this case you should remove `default.html` from `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html` and flush cache to see changes.

Or run this command to **clear static files** from pub

> php bin:magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Do you need to add the xml layout or anything

Comment: No @jibingeorge

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a softer approach to removing them via CSS, fortunately the layout renedered is set on the `body` class, for Example for the Checkout page:

`<body class="checkout-index-index ...">`

So you could add a `display` scope to the minicart:

```css
/* The Edit & Remove Buttons */
body.checkout-index-index #mini-cart .product.actions,
body.checkout-index-index #mini-cart .details-qty {
    display: none;
}
```