# Magento2: how to remove edit product link from minicart (2.4.1)

Tags: magento2

I have attempted to follow lots of answers on here which cover overriding the minicart via a new extension/module.

I have successfully removed all the edit links from the cart by adding the file:
checkout_cart_index.xml
to this location:
/app/design/frontend/BlackRhino/luma/Magento_Checkout/layout/

Which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.virtual.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.giftcard.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.downloadable.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle.actions.edit" remove="true"/>
</body>
```

Can I do the same for the minicart?

I have tried copying the file from this location:
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html

Various locations seem to be suggested:
/app/design/frontend/BlackRhino/luma/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/
/app/design/frontend/BlackRhino/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item
/app/code/BlackRhino/BlackForest/template/minicart/item/

I've tried all of these locations with deploying static content (although its in developer mode) but the pencil prevails.

I don't know if things have changed recently, quite alot of the questions appear to be 3-4 years old in some cases and I wonder if the recent changes now require a slightly different approach?

I have also tried to override this file:
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js
by placing one here with an alternative location like this:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html':
            'BlackRhino_BlackForest/template/minicart/content.html'
    }
}
```

};

but this answer [Magento 2: How to override mini-cart default template html file?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file) doesn't make it clear where the alternative file should be located and again is 5+ years old.

I wonder if someone could put me out my misery and tell me where I have gone wrong and which one of these solutions should work and how I can get it to work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place `defalt.phtml` to below path

> app/design/frontend/BlackRhino/luma/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/

and make require changes in html to remove the edit action.

Do static-content:deploy

```
php bin:magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

You can further check whether this file is overridden through theme by navigating to

> pub/static/frontend/BlackRhino/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html

Follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/190038/84221) for reference

Comment: Thank you @Rahul Barot - I was able to get this to work although its probably worth mentioning that the deploying of static files seems to give mixed results it took a few attempts to get the changes to appear - but the fact you told me it should work I was able to keep going to get the end result.

Comment: @UrbanwarfareStudios You're welcome.