# How to remove edit button from minicart?

Tags: magento2.3.4

i am trying to remove the edit button from the minicart dropdown, and followed the instructions listed out here - [How to remove edit and delete button from minicart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190006/how-to-remove-edit-and-delete-button-from-minicart/190038#190038)

However, after following all the steps, and running the setup:static-content:deploy, setup:di:compile and cache:flush commands, the edit button still appears on the frontend minicart.

Even when i removed the entire - div class="product actions" - section, both the edit button and remove product buttons appear.

i even cleared browsing history on browser, and used incognito, but still the same.

Would there be some step i am missing?

Comment: make sure with enable template path hints that your extension phtml file will be load.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i go about doing that @S.P ?

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-template-path-hints-magento-2.html
First check and make sure your updated phtml page will be loaded.

Comment: Did you replace "Vendor/theme" in the path to your file you were overriding? Also, sometimes depending on your deploy mode it can help if you flush Static Files Cache in the Magento admin

Comment: Thanks for the reply @rushtoni88 , yes i did replace vendor/theme in the path. i also did flush static cache in the admin backend. the edit button still showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using the magento2 theme then follow the below steps to remove the edit button in the mini cart.

1. Go to **app/design/frontend/vendor/themename/** and create here **Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item**.
2. Copy template **default.html** file form **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item** and upload above floder which you create in your theme in step1.
3. In this file remove the below code to remove the edit button from the mini cart.

`<!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility --> <div class="primary"> <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit"> <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span> </a> </div> <!-- /ko -->`

After then run the below command:

**bin/magento setup:upgrade**

**bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes i did all that, and the edit button still showing up.